# Show null if no result for certain field

Tags: sql, null

I'm using sql server 2008.  I'm trying to show a null result for amount and transdate, but still show the project name.

My query is:

```
select project, amount, transdate 
from rec 
where transdate>'2017-05-01' 
  and project like 'project%'
```

When I execute this I get no results, just blank.  What I'd like to see is.

```
project 1 | null | null
project 2 | null | null
project 3 | null | null
```

Comment: sql 10.5? What is that?

Comment: There is no such thing as "SQL 10.5" Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `OR` between checking the transdate for range and checking for null like so:

```
select project,
    amount,
    transdate
from rec
where (
        transdate is null
        or transdate > '2017-05-01'
        )
    and project like '%out'
```

Comment: @Nick please show your table schema with your expected data.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you'd like but it sounds like you want to return all projects regardless of whether it meets the criteria in your WHERE clause.  You should be able to get the result by joining the table to itself via LEFT JOIN:

```
select 
  r1.project,
  r2.amount,
  r2.transdate
from rec r1
left join rec r2
  on r1.project = r2.project  -- I'd change this to the PK on your table
  and r2.transdate > '2017-05-01'
  and r2.project like '%out';
```

Here is a [demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/667450).

Answer (score 0):

```
select project, amount, transdate 
from rec 
where 
(transdate>'2017-05-01' or transdate is null)
  and project like 'project%'
```